# JavaFX getting path of image store in Imageview with the help of filechooser need help D:

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, fxml, filechooser

my question is that I need help with getting the path from a image within a imageview in fxml file as I need to store the path of the image in an object. I am using a filechooser to input image into the imageView. I am planning to store that path into a object and claim it out at a later time like a profile page would keep the profile picture. I know it is abit brief but I hope if you guys got any way of helping me out it will be appreciated.

So based on the comments I edited: 
**My problem is I cannot claim the URL of the image path although i using a filechooser.** I have actually remove out all the relevant parts regarding the claiming of URL that i made as i cannot claim it out.

```
    package orgRegistrationtest;

public class OrgRegistrationController {

@FXML
private JFXHamburger hamburger;

@FXML
private JFXTextField email;

@FXML
private JFXCheckBox health;

@FXML
private JFXCheckBox animal;

@FXML
private JFXCheckBox children;

@FXML
private JFXCheckBox elderly;

@FXML
private JFXCheckBox environment;

@FXML
private JFXCheckBox others;

@FXML
private JFXTextField name;

@FXML
private JFXTextField contact;

@FXML
private JFXTextField address;

@FXML
private JFXPasswordField password;

@FXML
private JFXPasswordField password2;

@FXML
private JFXTextArea desc;

//pic not added 

@FXML
private ImageView pic;

@FXML
private JFXButton upload;

@FXML
private JFXButton clear;

@FXML
private JFXButton confirm;

@FXML
private JFXDrawer drawer;

@FXML
void handleClear(ActionEvent event) {

}


private String type=null;



@FXML

     private void handleConfirmButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        if(health.isSelected())
            type=health.getText();
        if(animal.isSelected()){
            type+=";"+animal.getText();
        }
        if(children.isSelected()){
            type+=";"+children.getText();
        }
        if(elderly.isSelected()){
            type+=";"+elderly.getText();
        }
        if(environment.isSelected()){
            type+=";"+environment.getText();
            }
        if(others.isSelected()){
            type+=";"+others.getText();
        }

        String Email=email.getText();
        String Password = password.getText();
        String Password2=password2.getText();
        String Name = name.getText();
        String Contact= contact.getText();
        String Address=address.getText();
        String Type = ""+type;
        String Desc = desc.getText();
        //String url = pic.getImage()._____
        //.getURL(); i know getURL is not inside same for getPath();
        // So how am i able to claim the Path of the Image and store it?


        OrgData table = new OrgData(Email,Password,Password2,Name, Contact,Address,Type,Desc,url);

        OrgDataDAO dao = new OrgDataDAO();
        dao.createFriend(table);




}




@FXML
public void handleUpload(ActionEvent t) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    //Set extension filter


    //Show open file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
        pic.setImage(image);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}


private Main Main;

public Main getMainApp() {
    return Main;
}

// setter for mainApp
public void setMainApp(Main testmainApp) {
    this.Main = testmainApp;
}
```

This is the model I have I never put in a String for the URL yet as i unable to sort of claim it out and there may be a better way to do instead of using the path although I did try out and it give me nothing.

```
  public class OrgData implements Serializable {
private String email, pw, pw2, name, contact, address, type, desc,url;

final static ObservableList<OrgData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


public OrgData(String email, String pw, String pw2, String name, String contact, String address, String type,
        String desc,String url) {
    super();
    this.email = email;
    this.pw = pw;
    this.pw2 = pw2;
    this.name = name;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.address = address;
    this.type = type;
    this.desc = desc;
    //this.url = url;
}

//public String getUrl() {
//  return url;
//}

//public void setUrl(String url) {
//    this.url= url;
//}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPw() {
    return pw;
}

public void setPw(String pw) {
    this.pw = pw;
}

public String getPw2() {
    return pw2;
}

public void setPw2(String pw2) {
    this.pw2 = pw2;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}



public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}



public static ObservableList<OrgData> getData() {
    return data;
}

public String toString(){
    return "["+email+","+pw+","+name+","+contact+","+address+","+type+","+desc+","+url+"]";
}
```

So this is the DAO where I save the file details at the end after users has click on the registered button and stored in the OrgRegData.dat file.
So like I said, My problem is that I am unable to take the path from the imageView image that i pick from the filechooser and stored it in to my model even as a String as there is no getPath() or getURL(); sort of method after clicking on the registered. I am not using a database or anything just using files and text files to store the data and reading the data from the files, so I hope is more clearer now with my problem

```
    public class OrgDataDAO {
private static final String Friend_File="OrgRegData.dat";
private File dataFile;


public OrgDataDAO() {
    Path dPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("resources/data/",Friend_File);
    dataFile=new File(dPath.toString());     
}

public ObservableList<OrgData> getAllFriends() {
    Scanner in;
    String record=null;
    String[] fields;
    ImageView[] images;

    ObservableList<OrgData> friends=FXCollections.observableArrayList();;
    try {
        in=new Scanner(dataFile);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            record=in.nextLine();
            fields=record.split(",");
            String email=fields[0];
            String password=fields[1];
            String password2=fields[2];
            String name=fields[3];
            String contact = fields[4];
            String address=fields[5];
            String type=fields[6];
            String desc=fields[7];
            //String url = fields[8];

            OrgData f=new OrgData(email,password,password2,name,contact,address,type,desc,url);
            friends.add(f);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("No record found!");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return friends;
}

/* assuming friend has a unique name, otherwise may return a list */
public OrgData getEvent(String email) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ObservableList<OrgData> event=getAllFriends();
    OrgData Event=null;
    for (OrgData f:event) {
        if (f.getEmail().equals(email)){
            Event=f;
            break;
        }
    }
    return Event;
}

public void updateEvent(OrgData Event) {
    ObservableList<OrgData> Events=getAllFriends();
    for (int i=0; i<Events.size(); i++) {
        OrgData f=Events.get(i);
        if (f.getEmail().equals(Event.getEmail())){
            Events.set(i, Event);
        }
    }
    synToFile(Events);
}

public void deleteEvent(OrgData Event) {

    ObservableList<OrgData> Events=getAllFriends();

    OrgData delEvent=null;
    for (OrgData f:Events) {
        if (Event.getEmail().equals(f.getEmail())){
            delEvent=f;         
            break;
        }
    }
    if (delEvent!=null){
        Events.remove(delEvent);
        synToFile(Events);      
    }       

}

public boolean createFriend(OrgData Event) {
    boolean existing=false;
    ObservableList<OrgData> Events=getAllFriends();
    for (OrgData f:Events) {
        if (f.getEmail().equals(Event.getEmail())){
            existing=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!existing) {
        Events.add(Event);
        synToFile(Events);
    }
    return !existing;
}

private void synToFile(ObservableList<OrgData> EventList) {
    if (EventList==null)
        return;

    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(dataFile);
        for (OrgData f: EventList) {
            out.append(f.toString()+"\n");
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: So what kind of difficulties you're having - please edit the question and add the relevant code.

Comment: When you get the file from the `FileChooser`, you know the path, so where's the problem???

Comment: Edited the question, If there is a need to show physical view of how the fxml look like i will put out later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reconsider storing the image just as `Image` object.

An `Image` object does not contain any information about the path (as you've already found out), since you can load it from any `InputStream` and there may not be a way to access the `InputStream` using a `URL`. (E.g. the image could be stored as a blob in a database making a query necessary to retrieve it...)

Store the url in a additional field when you open the file.

Furthermore I recommend using the `Image` class to load the image directly, since otherwise you create a `BufferedImage` and a `Image` object in memory which takes approx. twice the memory required for only one of those objects; the `BufferedImage` is available for garbage collection immediately after the method returns anyway...

```
private String imageUrl;

@FXML
private void handleUpload(ActionEvent t) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    //Set extension filter


    //Show open file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            imageUrl = file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
            Image image = new Image(imageUrl);
            pic.setImage(image);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}

@FXML
private void handleConfirmButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    ...
    String url = imageUrl;
    ...
}
```

Note that if you add a default image in the fxml, you need to initialize `imageUrl` with this url.

Comment: Hi, so i have tried out the answer u gave to me and i manage make it work for URL(String) but I am trying your suggestion to use an image object, I am able to change the relevant parts in my model and controller but the problem is with the DAO. How can i change it to be able to store it and gather the image.

Comment: @Devilsbats Do you need to include the image data in the file? Then a text file would not be well suited(but it could be done by encoding  the image data as string; it would probably be better to store the files in a archive though). Otherwise the file can be constructed from the url stored in the file...

Comment: Nevermind, i think i mix up what u meaning after reading alot of examples. i will give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

The basic filechooser functions are

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

String imgAddress3;
if (file != null) {
    try {
        imgAddress3 = file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
        Image image = new Image(imgAddress3);
        imageId.setImage(image);

        System.out.println(imgAddress3);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
```

And for clarification, you can see this full project.
https://github.com/ashrafulais/java_projects/tree/master/onCLickImageLoader